# How to fit response plot using square wave

Tags: filter, curve-fitting

I'm looking for a way/method to fit my response data (Image is shown below). So using `f(t) = (square(2*pi*f*t)+1)` to filter my raw data. However, cftool don't recognize this kind of function. So please help me thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Essential information is missing. What is your input? Which language/library do you intend to use? What exactly has the function to do with your diagram?

Comment: I find the signal very interesting, it is as if a high-frequency, low amplitude square wave with ringing is imposed on another function. Would you please post a link to the data? Except for the data itself, your posting provides sufficient information for me to use in analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The function below might allow to fit the data. It is continuous, but not differentiable everywhere. The steps tend to fall to the right, while OPs data does not. This might require some extra work. Moreover, steps have to be equidistant, which, however, seems to be the case.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f( x, a, b ): # test function (that would be the one to fit, actually + a shift of edge position)
    return a + b * x**3

def f_step( x, l, func, args=None ):
    y = ( x - l / 2. ) % l - l / 2.
    y = y / l * 2.
    p = np.floor( ( x-l/2.) / (l) ) + 1
    centre = p * l
    left = centre - l / 2.
    right = centre + l / 2.
    fL = func( left, *args )
    fR = func( right, *args )
    fC = func( centre, *args )
    out = fC + sharp( y , fL - fC, fR - fC , 5 )
    return out

def sharp( x, a, b , p, epsilon=1e-1 ):
    out = a * ( 1. / abs( x + 1 + epsilon )**p - ( 2 + epsilon)**( -p ) ) / ( epsilon**( -p ) - ( 2 + epsilon )**( -p ) ) 
    out += b * ( 1. /abs( x - 1 - epsilon )**p - ( 2 + epsilon)**( -p ) ) / ( epsilon**( -p ) - ( 2 + epsilon )**( -p ) ) 
    return out

l=0.57
xList = np.linspace( -1, 1.75, 500 )
yList = [ f_step( x, l, f, args=(2, -.3 ) ) for x in xList ] 

fig1 = plt.figure( 1 )
ax = fig1.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xList, yList )
ax.plot( xList, f(xList, 2,-.3) )
plt.show()
```

Looks like:

[image: Steps with varying height]